# how to split multiple rows in the same column into different columns depending on the data provided postgres

Tags: postgresql, pivot

so this is what I have...

| id | name | children | children's age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rachel | john | 20 |
| 1 | Rachel | cell | 10 |
| 1 | Rachel | jay | 15 |
| 2 | Jereme | Les | 17 |
| 2 | Jereme | greg | 5.5 |
| 2 | Jereme | ven | 27 |

but I'm trying to find a way to get this kind of results......

| id | name | child1 | age | child2 | age | child3 | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rachel | john | 20 | cell | 10 | jay | 15 |
| 2 | Jereme | Les | 17 | greg | 5.5 | ven | 27 |

so if I can get any help in the query part.... I'm still a beginner in psql so if you can explain as well... thank you

Comment: You may find a related answer to this question here https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/311054/152218 However, what I see from your example is that you're converting unique users to columns which makes little logical sense since in this case a single row represents multiple users with no unique denominator. You might want to clarify your question, include real data and definition of your tables etc.

Comment: @Chessbrain crosstab doesn't work with what I want.... ids 1 and 2 are the unique ids, and the names in column a are subsets of the column id(they belong to), with the values in column b which belong to the names in a......I don't know if you get me now?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to achieve this? You usually try to avoid this exact thing. There will probably not be a simple SQL to do this, since you try to convert a table which could contain any amount of rows into a pivot with rows for three children. Honestly, I'd probably do it in another programming language, but you have a lot of edge cases (what if there are more than 3 children? what if there are less?) and querying this table is a nightmare (what if child1 is empty, but there is a value in child2?). You might be better off using datatypes like arrays or json.

Comment: So why doesn't cross-tab/pivot work? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4998d32f0cf14604f63a8944a3c219c9

Comment: @FlouridFlour it was what was requested of me to do, so I have been searching for ways to do so if it was possible....

Comment: @Charlieface thank you so much.... this is what I wanted..... also crosstab doesn't work cause there's a cte as part of the query, and I tried to pivot the results as well since they are the same, but it didn't work as intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard conditional aggregation (pivot) query should work

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.name,
  MAX(t.children) FILTER (WHERE t.rn = 1) AS child1,
  MAX(t.age)      FILTER (WHERE t.rn = 1) AS age1,
  MAX(t.children) FILTER (WHERE t.rn = 2) AS child2,
  MAX(t.age)      FILTER (WHERE t.rn = 2) AS age2,
  MAX(t.children) FILTER (WHERE t.rn = 3) AS child3,
  MAX(t.age)      FILTER (WHERE t.rn = 3) AS age3
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.id, t.name ORDER BY t.children) AS rn
    FROM YourTable t
) t
GROUP BY
  t.id,
  t.name;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4998d32f0cf14604f63a8944a3c219c9)

Comment: Is it possible to add a condition? For example if there was an additional row like this... 3 | Larry | Grey | 12   ...... so if Larry is called, then it'll just show the columns "child1" and "age" ignoring the rest.... I don't know if something like that is possible?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. my query would get this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=76d1a3aca81a5687421571c5342a51ce is that not what you want? If you mean that you want the number of columns to be dynamic, I would advise you not to go down that route, it's very messy

Comment: Not really....I'm using metabase , so it displays as a question(not showing the query part just the results, and based on the filters used).... so I want it like based on the info wanted, it'd either display or not.... I don't know if you get me now?

Comment: so let's add another row....4 | Jer | white | 16...... if I want to just call on Larry and Jer, it should show the results for id, name, child1 and age....... So like there's no need to change the info in the query, but just on the filters used...(let's make id, and name as the filters)

Comment: No I don't get you at all. Perhaps you just want a `WHERE` filter? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8e4c33c692f7af1d1056711f3046b42e I think you might need to make a new question for this

Comment: if there was a call function or vn in stackexchange like I'd be able to explain better so you understand..... but thanks anyway.... you helped me a lot

Comment: @w123: If you mean you want the output to have a different number of columns (children and their ages) depending on how many is required to accommodate the output data, then that is not possible with regular SQL. What you'd need here is dynamic SQL. It would involve first running a query to find out the maximum number of children per person in the output, then constructing a text string representing a query with just the right number of output columns, and finally having that string evaluated (executed) to produce the output. You can look up "Dynamic SQL" to learn how it's done in PostgreSQL.

Comment: oh okay, will research on that... thank you @AndriyM